# SwiperJS get crushed by using GRID

Tags: layout, grid, swiper.js

i'm working on some website. I wanted to add a Cube Effect by swiper.js.
But when i'm adding into my JS an [effect: 'cube',] the whole website is going crazy :/

But if delete  [effect: 'cube',] OR use flex-box instead of GRID, everything works?

Plz help

https://github.com/AdamZajler/First-Website

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a position: absolute; FOR .swiper-wrapper